# How to build an installed package?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-hydro, build, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have installed ROS Hydro version (full install) and MoveIt!. In the /opt/ros/hydro/share folder there are many installed packages (e.g. /moveit_ros_benchmarks) but I can't find what it is supposed to be. In almost every folder there are only:

-/cmake (with two .cmake files inside)
-package.xml

I tried to build it to get the files needed, following the "building packages" ROS tutorials but it didn't work. I also re-installed desired packages from source with no change. So I don't know if I'm having some issues with the packages building or with rights to build in that location. I'm expecting the package shown in the benchmarking tutorial in the Moveit! wiki, with "moveit_benchmark_statistics.py" or "run_benchmark_ompl.launch" files in it.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110426/how-to-build-an-installed-package?/) by [dinomoracs](https://answers.ros.org/users/9921/dinomoracs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The file is part of the source repository (https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/blob/hydro-devel/benchmarks/benchmarks/scripts/moveit_benchmark_statistics.py) but is currently not being installed correctly. This is a bug in the released Debian package (I filled https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/issues/389).

You can either wait for a fix to be released by the maintainers or checkout the source repository and compile the package on your own (without installing it).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0